# Custom error messages on Rails not showing up - default "is invalid" showing instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model, I have a simple validation like so:

```
class Post
    validate :max_tag_limit, if: :tags

    private
    def max_tag_limit
        errors[:tags] << "You can only have maximum of 3 tags") if tags.count > 3
    end
end
```

The controller adds the error messages to flash like so:

```
  if !@post.save
     content = "Something went wrong - "
     @post.errors.full_messages.each { |msg| content += "#{msg} : " }
     flash[:error] = content
  end
```

I display my error messages using this helper function in my ApplicationHelper module:

```
  def flash_display
    response = ""
    flash.each do |name, msg|
      response = response + content_tag(:div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}")
    end
    flash.discard
    response
  end
```

I insert the message through js like so:

```
// add the flash message
$('#flash').html("<%= escape_javascript raw(flash_display) %>");
```

But i cannot for the life of me understand why Rails refuses to show my custom error message: "You can only have maximum of 3 tags". Instead it shows the rather cold inhuman message:
"Tags is invalid :".

What am i doing wrong people? Help!

EDIT: Debugging reveals some more info, which should hopefully narrow my question.

```
 @post.errors.full_messages
```

This contains only the "is invalid" message for each of my tags. I guess this means the messages i'm adding at the model, is clearly not being picked up (or is stored in the wrong location)

Comment: how do you set the flash message?

Comment: hmm. you ask a good question :D.

I presumed adding to the errors in the model, would take care of that for me. But that definitely seems wrong now. Do you have a suggestion for when i can add the flash message? typically I would do this in the controller, but my whole point was to move that logic into the model.

Comment: `flash` is the controller business, it must remain there. You could abstract your code with a private method of yours to dry things up

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving . added the relevant code to the question.

Comment: I'm confused about why you're including the message through js, given that the embedded ruby can only be run server side, how would this work?  If it's happening server side, why not just put it straight in the temlate?

Comment: @muttonlamb : I'm actually doing an ajax call, and on success/failure I return the view "create.js.erb". Within this js.erb file I have the condition that adds in the flash message. So yes, it is run server side. Though i don't think that is the issue here, since the messages are flowing through. Just that the right message isn't.

Comment: You're not doing a redirect, so you don't need the flash.

Comment: @mischa : I didn't get you. I use flash as a mechanism to display errors and warnings on my page. The behavior of flash would accordingly change if i did a redirect/render. But i would think i definitely would need an object to capture my warnings/errors (which is what the flash object is meant for)?

Comment: What is `@news_item`? Earlier you are talking about `@post`. Please make sure your question is consistent.

Comment: @mischa  My bad. corrected \@news_item to \@post

Comment: Did you see my new answer? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you should use [`errors[:base]`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#errors-base) instead of `errors[:tags]`:

```
class Post
  validate :max_tag_limit, if: :tags

  private

  def max_tag_limit
    errors[:base] << "You can only have maximum of 3 tags" if tags.count > 3
  end
end
```

And you should not be using the flash if you're not redirecting.